# Suppose $x=f(s,t)$ and $y=g(s,t)$, what is $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $x=f(s,t)$ and $y=g(s,t)$, how do we calculate

$$\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Should I use chain rule? I looked at [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), I got

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\frac{\text{d}s}{\text{d} x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\frac{\text{d}t}{\text{d} x}$$

Comment: Are you sure this is what you mean? In your case, $x=y$. Edit: Now that you've edited the question, I've taken the liberty of editing your title for you.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Sorry, I made a typo.

Comment: in terms of what do you want the derivative? Is there anymore context in this question (for example, conditions on the partial derivatives of G or F?)

Comment: @qbert Not really. It just asks me to find an expression for that.

Comment: You can get the derivative $dy/dx$ in terms of $ds/dt$ and partial derivatives of $f, g$. If $s, t$ are independent variables then $x, y$ are also independent variables and hence it does not make sense to talk of $dy/dx$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, we start with equations $x = f(s, t), y = g(s, t)$. The derivative $dy/dx$ makes sense only when $x, y$ are dependent variables i.e. there is some relation of the form $\phi(x, y) = 0$ between them. Differentiating this relation with respect to $s$ and $t$ we get $$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = 0, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = 0$$ And eliminating the derivaives of $\phi$ we get the Jacobian $$\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(s, t)} = \begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\\ \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\end{vmatrix} = 0$$ Note that the above condition is also sufficient for existence of a functional equation between $x, y$ and then the derivative $dy/dx$ is given by the relation $d\phi = 0$ or $$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\cdot dx + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\cdot dy = 0$$ or $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\partial \phi/\partial x}{\partial \phi/\partial y} = \frac{\partial y/\partial s}{\partial x/\partial s} = \frac{\partial y/\partial t}{\partial x/\partial t}$$ or $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial s}}{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial s}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial t}}{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}}$$ As a simple example let $$x = f(s, t) = s + t, y = g(s, t) = s + t$$ so that $y = x$ and $dy/dx = 1$. Clearly we have $\partial y/\partial s = 1, \partial x/\partial s = 1$ so that $dy/dx = \dfrac{\partial y/\partial s}{\partial x/\partial s} = 1$.

To convince yourself you can try a slightly complicated example $$x = f(s, t) = s + t, y = g(s, t) = (s + t)^{2} = s^{2} + t^{2} + 2st$$

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer makes sense, but it disagrees with my try... Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @user34183: your application of total derivative rule is wrong. You have $$dy = \frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\cdot ds + \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\cdot dt$$ and similar expression for $dx$. But dividing the two you don't get the derivative $dy/dx$ because you are not sure whether $x, y$ are independent or dependent. A proper analysis like I have done in my answer is necessary.

Comment: @user34183: I checked your last edit and the total derivative rule is correct, but you don't know if $ds/dx$ or $dt/dx$ makes sense because you don't know if $s, t $ are functions of $x$.

Comment: I am still confused. Why _wouldn't_ $s,t$ be functions of $x$? Is it inverse function issue?

Comment: Also, if $s = u(x,y)$ and $t=v(x,y)$, how can I show that two expressions are equivalent?

Comment: why the downvote??

Comment: @user34183: suppose $x=s+t$ then how is $s$ a function of $x$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh i dont know why this was downvoted, it is an excellent explanation, +1

Comment: @qbert: Glad you liked my answer. BTW it appears that the downvoting was performed on this whole thread (both the question and all the answers including yours were downvoted). Some users on MSE have this behavior that if they downvote a question they also downvote all the answers. If there is an issue with question, then it is better to ask OP for clarification and get the question edited rather to downvote the whole thread.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ah I hadn't noticed that. My answer was also wrong. Do you have any good resources for practice with problems such as these?

Comment: @qbert: Can't help much with any resources related to problem solving because I am no longer an active student (check my profile). I can suggest you some good references on calculus if you wish. My two favorite books are *A Course of Pure Mathematics* by G. H. Hardy and *Mathematical Analysis* by Tom M. Apostol. Hardy's book is a classic and unparalleled even after a century has passed since it was first published.